# How to perform ng-include with button?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, view

I am having trouble trying to perform an ng-include when I click a button. Here is my code:

Main.html:

```
<div class="main">
    <div ng-include="(manage.show && 'dsManage.html') || dsSelect.html"></div>
    <h1>Data Sources</h1>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" >
        <div ng-show="reportManage && (reportManage.canManage || reportManage.canManageAll)">
            <div class="row searchRow">
                <span class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                    <span class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control searchInput" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><img ng-if="search" src="../images/Search_clear.png" ng-click="clearSearch()"/></span>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-4 text-right">
                    <a ng-show="tileLayout" class="btn-list-view" ng-click="tileLayout=false">List View</a>
                    <a ng-show="!tileLayout" class="btn-tile-view" ng-click="tileLayout=true">Tile View</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-left">
                <button ng-click="showDatasources()">All/Default</button>
                <button ng-click="showManagePage()">Manage</button>
                <!--<a href="{{dsSelectAllDefault}}" id="btn-default-all"></a>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Main.js:

```
$scope.showManagePage = function() {
    console.log("True");
    $scope.manage.show = true;
}
```

Basically what I want is that when I click the `Manage` button, `showManagePage()` will trigger and cause the `ng-include` at the very top of the code to trigger and show `dsManage.html`. This will replace the existing view, `dsSelect.html`, with `dsManage.html`. However, whenever I press this button, nothing occurs. The thing is these pages are in my root directory and when i add the `./` prefix to my files, my page seems to crash. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

EDIT: Updated Main.html file:

```
<div class="main">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" >
        <div ng-show="manage.show" ng-include="'dsManage.html'"></div>
        <div ng-show="!manage.show">
            <h1>Data Sources</h1>
            <div ng-show="reportManage && (reportManage.canManage || reportManage.canManageAll)">
                <div class="row searchRow">
                    <span class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                        <span class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control searchInput" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><img ng-if="search" src="../images/Search_clear.png" ng-click="clearSearch()"/></span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-4 text-right">
                        <a ng-show="tileLayout" class="btn-list-view" ng-click="tileLayout=false">List View</a>
                        <a ng-show="!tileLayout" class="btn-tile-view" ng-click="tileLayout=true">Tile View</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-left">
                    <button ng-click="showDatasources()">All/Default</button>
                    <button ng-click="showManagePage()">Manage</button>
                    <!--<a href="{{dsSelectAllDefault}}" id="btn-default-all"></a>-->
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am now getting an issue saying `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.` and I notice I only get this error when I perform the `ng-include`. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I don´t understand pretty well what your problem is. It can´t reach the partial file?

Why do you declare the `ng-include` _outside_ the `ng-controller` element? The `$scope.manage` object its declared in some parent scope?

Comment: `ng-include="(manage.show && 'dsManage.html') || dsSelect.html"` shouldn´t work properly, I would rewrite it like `ng-include="(manage.show) ? 'dsManage.html':'dsSelect.html'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your manage.show  is outside the scope of controller MainCtrl.
Try moving the DIV with ng-include inside the controller DIV. or move the controller declaration to the div with class main.